# HTML 5 Video Problems, video won't play on page but can right click and download and view in browser

Tags: html5-video

I'm stumped. After reading numerous blogs and posts regarding this, here is the code I compiled to get full browser support for my html 5 videos

```
<video width="686" height="284" poster="http://my_S3_file.png?preset=category-hero" autoplay loop> 
        <source src="http://my_S3_file.theora.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
        <source src="http://my_S3_file.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
        <source src="http://my_S3_file.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
        <object width="686" height="284" src="http://my_S3_file.mp4">
            <embed width="686" height="284" src="http://my_S3_file.swf" loop="false" wmode="transparent" ></embed>
        </object>
    </video>
```

Works great in Chrome (as always). However, Firefox and IE refuse to play. Whats even more strange, in firefox I can right-click on the video area and select view video, open the webm file in a new tab and view it in the browser. What is the deal!?

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late response perhaps.

Have you set the correct MIME-types for the files when you uploaded them?